# How to use Slack API and OAuth2 to signup and authenticate for an android app?

Tags: slack-api

I am looking to mimic the function of "Sign Up with Facebook" but with Slack instead, using their API and Oauth2.

Has this ever been done before and/or is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here are the docs for authenticating against the Slack API.](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth)

Then use the [auth.test endpoint](https://api.slack.com/methods/auth.test) to get the current user's ID.

Finally you make a call to the [users.info endpoint](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.info) to get the e-mail, first name, last name of the user.